# REST url with mvc controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, url

Maybe I'm missing something but I can not pass a small issue

I'm building a simple Spring Boot app and I am using MVC Controller: `@Controller` annotation

In my controller I have

```
@GetMapping("/trainee")
public String trainee(@RequestParam("id") long id, Model model) {
```

to enter that method I need to prepare url like this: `/trainne?id=1` and I would prefer `/trainee/1`

I know that the second option is possible with REST Controller but I can not use it cause it does not support templates. Can I make a nice REST type url with mvc controller?

I will also add

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/trainees")
public class TraineeController {
```

When I use mapping like @Ken Chan suggested I receive

```
2018-12-28 18:49:50.740 DEBUG 5960 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /trainees/trainee/1
2018-12-28 18:49:50.740 DEBUG 5960 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/trainees/trainee/1]
2018-12-28 18:49:50.740 DEBUG 5960 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /trainees/trainee/1
2018-12-28 18:49:50.740 DEBUG 5960 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/trainees/trainee/1]
2018-12-28 18:49:50.740 DEBUG 5960 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@6c120aea
```

// adding full debug according to @Ben configuration

```
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /trainees/trainee/1
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/trainees/trainee/1]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /trainees/trainee/1
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/trainees/trainee/1]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /trainees/trainee/1
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/trainees/trainee/1]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/trainees/trainee/1] are [/**]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/trainees/trainee/1] are {}
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/trainees/trainee/1] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@470d91ab]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@3b6c5f54
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/trainees/trainee/1]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /trainees/trainee/1
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/trainees/trainee/1]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /trainees/trainee/1
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/trainees/trainee/1]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.113 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /trainees/trainee/1
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/trainees/trainee/1]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/trainees/trainee/1] are [/**]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/trainees/trainee/1] are {}
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/trainees/trainee/1] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@470d91ab]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/trainees/trainee/1] is: -1
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.b.w.s.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@3b6c5f54
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/error]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] a.e.w.s.ControllerEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/error]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@517289db] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@517289db] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-12-28 21:22:43.128 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Comment: What 's wrong with this : `@GetMapping(value = " /trainee/{id}"` and `public String trainee(@ PathVariable("id") long id, Model model) ` ?

Comment: @KenChan I've updated my post. I don't want to say that something is wrong with your solution but it just doesn not work. I've already tried it (I'm sorry I've shoudl mention that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `@PathVariable` annotation on inputs to use the url patter matching

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/trainees")
public class TraineeController {

    @GetMapping("/trainee/{id}")
    public String trainee(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {
         // Your code here
    }

}
```

You can also add 
`logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG` to your `application.properties`  in order to check what mappings spring has set up for you

Comment: I've aready tried this and it is not working. I've posted the debug in the update of my post. As for me it can not find the pattern

Comment: hmm suddenly it started to work o.O I don't get it. I'll run few more tests

Comment: @Fixus perhaps you haven't cleaned or rebuilt your project, and just ran it with the old endpoint mapping?

Comment: @Fixus It's also worth noting that with the debug flag all the registered endpoints should be outputted during the initialization of spring application

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to make the REST type url with mvc controller. here is the bellow code to make the REST url.

```
     @Controller
     @RequestMapping("/trainees)
     @ResponseBody
     @RequestMapping(value="/update/{id}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
      public @ResponseBody  MehodName(@PathVariable ("id") Integer id)
      {
       //write the logic of the method
       }
```